# How to delete files in different directories in linux with a single command

Tags: linux

I've a directory structure which looks like this

```
main
  -in
      infile1.txt
      infile2.txt        
  -out
      outfile1.txt
      outfile2.txt
  -log
      logfile1.txt
      logfile2.txt
```

how can I delete files in all the sub directories which are 15 days old.

I know I can use following commands, but I want to do it using a single command.

```
find in/* -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \; 
find out/* -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \; 
find log/* -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: If you don't need to worry about preserving matching files in `main`, just run the command from there with an argument of `.` instead of a directory name. Or use `-mindepth`.

Comment: Why not use `&&` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) allows multiple starting points, so you can just do this:

```
find in out log -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Unix/Linux Stack Exchange...where I found this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136804/cron-job-to-delete-files-older-than-3-days

Seems similar to what you are looking for.